# Multi Currency and Closed Opportunities

Tags: opportunity, multi-currency, currency

We are in the process of enabling multi-currency, not advanced currency management.
We were told that updating corporate exchange rates would not only affect open opportunities but also closed opportunities.

This doesn't make much sense to me because changing exchange rates on closed (past opportunities) means you're modifying past revenue.

Is this true and/or is there a way to lock the exchange rate, at the opportunity level once it is closed (without having to use dated exchange rates)?

Comment: Great question! This is better suited for the Success Community (Trailblazers Community?) because it has to do with multicurrency and back-end features of Salesforce, not with custom code. Good luck!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs in the Trailblazer Community where the PMs can comment.